# ¿Lista de objetos en python?

Tags: python

soy nuevo en la programación de python y en este foro por lo que pido perdón por posibles fallos me intentare explicar lo mejor posible.

Estoy intentando hacer un bot en python y para ello quiero manejar mediante ficheros el almacenamiento de clientes. Para ello estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, name, phone, password, api_key, secret_api):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.password = password
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.secret_api = secret_api
    def visualizer(self):
        print( "Name: " + self.name)
        print( "Password: " + self.password)
        print("Phone number: " + self.phone)
        print("Api key: " + self.api_key)
        print("Secret api: " + self.secret_api)
lista_clientes = []
i = int(0)
name = str()
phone = str()
password = str()
api_key = str()
secret_api = str()
with open("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\python\\Clientes.txt", "r") as f:
    for linea in f:
        if i == 0:
            password = str(linea)
        if i == 1:
            name = str(linea)
        if i == 2:
            phone = str(linea)
        if i == 3:
            api_key = str(linea)
        if i == 4:
            secret_api = str(linea)
        if i == 5:
            lista_clientes.append(Cliente(name, phone, password, api_key, secret_api))
            i = 0
        i = i + 1
        
for element in lista_clientes:
    element.visualizer()
```

La idea basicamente es tener en cada 5 lineas del fichero un cliente e ir almacenandolos en una lista de clientes. El problema es que solo se me guarda en 1 posicion de la lista (lista_clientes[0]) aunque en el fichero tenga 2 clientes (10 lineas). A continuación dejaré un fichero .txt de prueba y la salida por consola al ejecutar el programa:
`
Fichero:

```
contra1
nombre1
numero1
api1
secret1
contra2
nombre2
numero2
api2
secret2
```

Salida por consola:

[image]

Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda y muchas gracias por leer mi pregunta.

Comment: No habías hecho ya una pregunta similar??

Comment: El formato .CSV (comma separated values) es el apropiado para guardar, recuperar y compartir información: tienes todo el cliente en una sola línea y el archivo lo puedes leer con bases de datos, pandas, excel y cualquier otro programa que lea .CSV.

Comment: @Christian Si, y me dijeron que volviese  a hacer la pregunta porque me pidieron el código escrito en vez de en imágenes

Comment: Nunca te dijeron que cuelgas ha hacer la 0regunta, solo tenias que editarla

Comment: @Christian mmm entiendo, gracias por el consejo lo tendre en cuenta la siguiente pregunta pues es la primera vez que pregunto, igualmente pienso que tu comentario no aporta nada asi que...

Comment: Sii... lo siento, tenia que decirlo para que lo sepas para próximas preguntas. Dar una respuesta ahora es innecesario, tal vez te ayude para la próxima :D

Answer (score 3):

Analicemos el código

#### Inicialización

```
i = int(0)
name = str()
```

La función `int` se ocupa para convertir una cadena en un entero; para inicializar un entero basta con asignarle un valor.

La función `str` se usa para obtener una representación imprimible de un objeto. Si quieres inicializar un string, basta con asignarle un valor:

```
i = 0
name = ''
```

#### Representación imprimible

En Python el método `__str__` de una clase es la manera estándar de obtener su representación imprimible. Debe retornar un string.

La clase  `Cliente` queda así:

```
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, name, phone, password, api_key, secret_api):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.password = password
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.secret_api = secret_api

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Name: {self.name} Password: {self.password} Phone number: {self.phone} Api key: {self.api_key} Secret api: {self.secret_api}"
```

Como práctica general, no es recomendable imprimir los resultados dentro del mismo método o función que los genera. Es más versátil devolver un string que pueda ser impreso, desplegado, o almacenado según convenga.

El método `__str__` se llama automáticamente cuando imprimes un objeto de la clase, o cuando usas explícitamente `str(objeto)`.

#### Lectura del archivo

Hay varias maneras de leer un archivo:

- `f.read()` Lee el contenido completo de una vez.
- `f.readlines()` Lee el archivo y devuelve una lista de líneas.
- `f.readline()` Lee una línea del archivo.

Estás usando `f.read`, por sólo la primera lectura retorna algo; las restantes lecturas retornan nada.

El inconveniente de `f.readlines()` es que con archivos grandes, consume grandes cantidades de RAM, CPU y tiempo leyendo, creando objetos y ampliando la lista. Si puedes, siempre es más conveniente procesar uno a uno los elementos.

Para leer un archivo línea por línea usas `f.readline()`. Está función te devuelve la línea completa, incluyendo el '\n' al final, que debes eliminar con la función `strip()`.

Cuando llegas al final del archivo, `f.readline()` retorna un string de largo cero; esa será nuestra señal para terminar el proceso.

#### Impresión

Como la clase `Cliente` ahora tiene un método `__str__`, basta con simplemente colocar el objeto en el `print`.

#### Demo

En está aplicación particular, no necesito inicializar previamente las variables; siempre tendrán algo que ha sido leido desde el archivo.

```
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, name, phone, password, api_key, secret_api):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.password = password
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.secret_api = secret_api

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Name: {self.name} Password: {self.password} Phone number: {self.phone} Api key: {self.api_key} Secret api: {self.secret_api}"


lista_clientes = []
with open("clientes.txt", "rt") as f:
    while True:
        name = f.readline().strip()
        if name == '':
            break
        name = name.strip()
        phone = f.readline().strip()
        password = f.readline().strip()
        api_key = f.readline().strip()
        secret_api = f.readline().strip()
        lista_clientes.append(Cliente(name, phone, password, api_key, secret_api))

for element in lista_clientes:
    print(element)
```

*Archivo clientes.txt*

```
juan
555-5555
contra
JJK(
LLK(
Jorge
1-800-30004
secreta
899983
88KKLM
```

produce

```
Name: juan Password: contra Phone number: 555-5555 Api key: JJK( Secret api: LLK(
Name: Jorge Password: secreta Phone number: 1-800-30004 Api key: 899983 Secret api: 88KKLM

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!